# Is there a 64 bit version of SSMS and BIDS with SQL Server 2008 64 bit?

Tags: sql-server

Today we had a very heated discussion at work regarding the availability of a 64 bit version of SSMS and BIDS with SQL Server 2008 64 bit.

While I know for sure that such a thing does not exist for SQL 2005, I could neither convince nor prove that this does not exist for SQL Server 2008 64 bit. The lead developer who claims that this exists even went to the extent of saying that with SQL 2008 64 bit, you can actually double click on an SSIS package and edit it within SSMS. I suspect the developer is referring to a maintenance plan.

Since we ran out of time, the discussion will continue tomorrow. I have searched the internet and Microsoft, but I am unable to find much documentation on this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Raj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I raised a case with Microsoft (being a Gold Certified partner helps:)). Here is the response

Thank you for contacting Microsoft Partner Pre-Sales Technical Support. It was nice talking with you. This is with reference to subject above. 
Non Decrement Case has been created for your reference: Case Number# SRSXXXXXXXXXXX - SQL Server 2008- Multiple Queries

Please take a moment to review the information and contact me with any comments you may have.

Product:

SQL Server 2008

Query

Multiple Queries

Solution:

1)  Is SQL Server Management Studio shipped with SQL Server 2008 64 bit , also 64 bit?
Ans: 
SQL Server Management Studio is a 32 bit application
Runtime Compatibility
SQL Server Management Studio 2008 runs in WOW64 mode on 64-bit clients. Because of this, the 32-bit version of SQL Server Compact must be installed to use the tools available within SQL Server Management Studio
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835497.aspx

2)  Is it possible to directly edit deployed SSIS packages from within Management Studio?
Ans: 
Currently you cannot load a package from Mgt studio for editing. From Mgt studio you can see what’s running, what’s stored, and can execute a package but not edit.
 Ref: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/9cc6a819-e7b5-40a2-b5b6-0957118ffed7/

For more discussion please let me know we can have conference call.

3)  Is there a 64 bit version of Business Intelligence Development Studio?
Ans: 
Business Intelligence Development Studio, the 32-bit development environment for Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services projects, is not designed to run on the Itanium 64-bit architecture and is not installed on Itanium servers.
Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767.aspx

Raj

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a 64-bit SSIS engine. I believe that BIDS is still 32-bit, like the rest of Visual Studio.

However, the SSMS I'm running now on 64-bit Vista is 32-bit.

Comment: Ooh yeah. I distinctly remember being bitten by the fact that compiled 32 bit SSIS tasks won't work on 64 bit.

Comment: John, how do you find if SSMS is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Task Manager. The process name is "Ssms.exe *32".

Comment: SSMS.exe *32???? Doesn't that make it 32 bit? Can you check an tell me the location of the .exe file? I think it would be in the (x86) folder if it is 32 bit.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE